# Install a Linux kernel with debug symbols and without optimizations

Tags: kernel, debugging, systemtap

My system is Ubuntu 18.04. How do I install a Linux kernel with debug symbols and without optimizations? I would like to trace it with SystemTap.

Comment: Compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu provides per-compiled kernels but these kernels won't have any debugging features you need. Here's a [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to a quick guide to compiling the Ubuntu release of Linux.

There's a section for enabling debug symbols at the bottom of the guide.

Regarding the compiling of the kernel without optimization -- that *can* be done for certain features within the kernel, but the kernel as a whole requires the -O2 flag to compile. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151235/how-to-de-optimize-the-linux-kernel-to-and-compile-it-with-o0).

Comment: The provided guide does not work because **rules** does not have the **recipies** used by the tutorial.